# systemd: Where is the `enabled-runtime` symlink?

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

```
miranda:~# systemctl is-enabled --full postfix@-
enabled-runtime
miranda:~# systemctl is-enabled --full tinydns
enabled
  /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tinydns.service
miranda:~# ls -la /run/systemd/system
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  40 Jan 20 07:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 620 Feb  1 16:35 ..
miranda:~#
```

According to the [systemctl man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) “enabled-runtime” should be a link somewhere in `/run/systemd/system`, but that directory is empty.—I’m trying to find out how my default instance of postfix (postfix@-) came into existence. It is shown as enabled-runtime, but even `--full` gives no explanation (as it does for e.g. tinydns).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the man page is wrong and thanks to [davolfman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/27395/davolfman)'s now-deleted comment, I found the link:

```
/run/systemd/generator/postfix.service.wants/postfix@-.service
```

(linking to `/lib/systemd/system/postfix@.service`).